# rails 4 uninitialized constant ActionController::RecordIdentifier

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am using:

```
gem 'ajaxful_rating', :git => "git://github.com/helloenvoy/ajaxful-rating", :branch => "rails4".
```

When I try to call method `rating_for`, throwing an error:

```
uninitialized constant ActionController::RecordIdentifier
```

Answer (score 4):

What verison of Rails are you using? The `ActionController::RecordIdentifier` was (re)moved to ActionView in Rails 4.1 and should be now used as a `ActionView::RecordIdentifier`.

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RecordIdentifier.html

So if you are using more recent version, you should change this line in the gem https://github.com/edgarjs/ajaxful-rating/blob/b223cba94702aa0229d084f8de976c0284ac4f36/lib/axr/stars_builder.rb#L48.